# c++ specialize a member function for vector

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I'm new to c++ and Im learning to use templates .
I want to make a template class with 2 template parameters,and to specialize a single member function from the class, for the case where the second template parameter is a vector templated on a pointer type of the first parameter. I think an example of what I tried  will be more clear :

```
//Container.h:

template<class T ,   class CONT  >
class Container {

private:
    CONT container;
    T    someData;
public:
    void foo();
};
```

and the specilization for std::vector I tried is:

```
//Container.cpp

template<class T>
void Container<T, std::vector<T*> > ::foo(){
     cout << "specialized foo:  " << container.pop_back(); 
    }

template<class T, class CONT  >
void Container<T, CONT > ::foo(){
     cout << "regular foo: " << container.pop_back());
}
```

but I get these erors:

```
error C3860: template argument list following class template name must list parameters in the order used in template parameter list
error C2976: 'Container<T,CONT>' : too few template argument
```

the usage of the Container class has to be that the 1st parameter is some type , and second is an STL container, vector or list. for example :

```
Container<int, vector<int*> > c;
c.foo();
```

what am I dong wrong ?

Comment: Apart from the syntax errors, you cannot specialize function templates partially, so this approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax to define a member function in Class template is

```
template<class T, class CONT > 
void Container<T, CONT>::foo()
{
     cout << "specialized foo:" ; 
}
```

**foo() function** is not overloaded and redefined. Redefinition of  **foo()** function also gives error. You can't overload function on the basis of return type. 
The specialization of std::vector is incorrect.
<< operator should also be overloaded You can'y use it directly like this

`cout << container.pop_back();`

Comment: I edited the syntax error, apart from that , you can assume operator << is overloaded , I just wanted to show that foo uses member function from container object.

Answer (score 1):

You could use policy based design. Now there are many variations on this, but a simple example goes like so

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, class CONT>
struct foo_policy {
    static inline void execute() {
        cout << "regular foo: \n" ;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct foo_policy<T, std::vector<T*>> {
    static inline void execute() {
        cout << "specialized foo: \n" ;
    }
};

template<class T ,   class CONT  >
class Container
{
private:
    CONT container;
    T    someData;
public:
    void foo()
    {
        foo_policy<T, CONT>::execute();
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Container<int, std::vector<int>>  a;
    Container<int, std::vector<int*>> b;
    a.foo();
    b.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

[Here's a demo](http://ideone.com/2mv2yA). In another scenario you could be deriving Container from the foo_policy class and using the base member's function (but there a bit more complex implications there)

Comment: thanks , I suppose  it will  do the work , but I thought there was a more straight-forward way for achieving this.